# Angularjs binding data from modal only on save

Tags: angularjs

I have created a table with rows of data. When clicking I have the scope available of the element selected. This then brings up a modal popup.

But when editing the modal it will obviously change the binding data on the row. But i only want to do this on save. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use angular.copy() to make an "editable" copy of the data and put it in the scope.  In your template reference this editable variable so that changes in the modal will be made to it instead of the actual data.  Then, in your save function update the actual data using angular.extend().  The extend() function will copy properties from the editable data to the actual data.

Comment: Cheers will give this a go

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the modal edit the the table data. Instead, make a copy of them, show this copy in your modal and, if the user saves, apply this new changes on your table's scope. Hope it helps.

Comment: You mean put it into a different scope?

Comment: Yes. When the user **clicks** on a specific row or data, copy that part of the scope into some new variables. Then make the modal access these copies. When the user saves, update the original scope. Does it make sense to you?